# Secure my WebApi1 application using oauth2

Tags: http, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api

I have an **MVC4 application** and Im using **WebAPI 1** to expose it to other applications. I want to secure it using oauth2. Please anyone provide me sufficient tutorials to use **oauth2**.

My requirement is that I need to provide some authentication header to my client application when it request(after a login or something) and when it request any data I need to check and verify the authentication header and only based upon the result my application can provide the data as response.

Anybody please show me a detailed example that help me to make my MVC application secure using oauth2.

**EDIT** : I have the resource server (my MVC4 webApi1 application). Actually what I need is that I have to make my application as an **identity provider** (**service provider**) (which one provides authorization token and verify it when the client application tries to access it) using ***oauth2***.

Answer (score 0):

The example would be too long to bring it here, I will then focus on major steps and all missing details are in the great **Pro ASP.NET Web API Security** book.

[http://www.amazon.com/Pro-ASP-NET-Web-API-Security/dp/1430257822](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430257822)

Naming conventions:

- **identity provider** - the application that can authenticate users
- **resource server** - the application exposing the WebAPI service (can be the same as the identity provider)
- **client application** - the application that wants to invoke the web api
- **resource owner** - the user who uses the client application

To start, you need to decide what type of oauth2 flow you want to implement.

- **authorization_code** - your end users will login to the client application using their web browsers via the identity server. The identity server exposes the token endpoint that the client application uses to obtain **access tokens**. With access tokens, the client application calls the resource server, where the WebAPI is protected with OAuth2
- **username password**  - the client application knows usernames and passwords (rather than asks the identity server to authenticate users) and can exchange them for access tokens in the identity server
- **client_credentials** - there is no end user, just the client application invokes some web api on behalf of itself

All flows end up with the client application having the access token. The access token is then passed in the header and the WebAPI at the resource server side is protected with a custom authentication attribute that sets the principal for the current request according to the information sent in the header.

There are tons of details but luckily, the book has a complete example that uses the DotNetOpenAuth library. You should be able to follow the example.

Comment: Please anyone provide me some free tutorials which helps to do it.

Comment: DotnetOpenAuth is free, has free documentation and free examples.